# In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

When running this code:

```
A(B<5) = C + (B-5)*5/10;
```

I'm getting the following error

```
In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are large matrices of same size (6399x6926). I could get it to work using a `for` loop, but it took more time.

Comment: It means that the size of `A(B<5)` and `C+(B-5)*5/10` must be the same. Do `size(A(B<5)` and `size(C+(B-5)*5/10)` before that line of code and you should understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that size of `A(B<5)` will typically be smaller then size of `A`. Size of `A(B<5)` will be equal to the number of elements of `B` that obey condition `B<5`.

Example:

```
B=[0 3 8 10]
A=[1 2 3 4]

A(B<5)=[1 2]
```

This is because only first two elements are less then 5.

Possibly, you wanted to do this:

```
A(B<5) = C(B<5) + (B(B<5)-5)*5/10;
```